# jQuery Combobox clickable icon

Tags: jquery, combobox, jquery-easyui

How to set action on icon in `Combobox` from `Easy UI` `jQuery` extension.
I use code below for define combobox element:

```
<select class="easyui-combobox" name="timeperiod" style="width:250px;"     data-options="icons:[{iconCls:'icon-clear'}]"
<option value="1">data 1</option>
<option value="2">data 2</option>
</select>
```

I want to set clear method for 'icon-clear' for this combobox element. How I can do it?

Is there any 'out of box' way to get it? I know I can simply set it using `jQuery` 'on' method. But I am looking native for combobox option.

Answer (score 0):

```
icons:[{
            iconCls:'icon-add',handler:function(){alert()}
}],
```